# Spring-data-redis/lettuce performance reduced

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis, lettuce

I developed an application with spring-boot 1.5.9, spring-data-redis 1.8.9 and lettuce 4.5.0.FINAL. Redis-server version is 6.0.5 I did performance benchmark on my machine for records (40 KB) insertion and the throughout is 2857 records inserted per sec.

I upgraded the application to spring-boot 2.3.1, spring-data-redis 2.3.1 and lettuce 5.3.1.FINAL. Redis-server version is 6.0.5. I didn't change the code to create connection. Just upgraded the spring boot. Now when I do benchmark, the performance is reduced lot. i.e., 1000 records (same 40KB) inserted per second.

Do we need to any configuration change after migrating to latest version?

Refer the code to create connection factory below:

```
@Bean
public LettuceConnectionFactory lettuceConnectionFactory()
{
    return new LettuceConnectionFactory(hostName, port);
}

@Bean
public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate(LettuceConnectionFactory lettuceConnectionFactory) 
{
    RedisTemplate<String, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
    template.setConnectionFactory(lettuceConnectionFactory);
    return template;
}
```

============ Updated the question

Below is the code used to benchmark the insertion

```
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Arrays.stream(persons).forEach(person -> {
        try {
            personRepository.save(person);
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            log.error("Error is ", e);
        }
    });
    long timeElapsed = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
    calculateThroughput(timeElapsed);
```

Where, persons is the array of Person objects. Throughput is calculated as below

```
 private void calculateThroughput(long timeElapsed)
    {
        long timeElapsedInSeconds = timeElapsed/1000;
        long recPerSec = noOfRecords/timeElapsedInSeconds;
        log.warn("It took {} milliseconds to persist {} number of records. i.e. {} records per second",
                timeElapsed, noOfRecords, recPerSec);
    }
```

Note that, I didn't change above after migrating to latest spring boot

Comment: It would be more helpful if you can show your benchmark code here. How did you do it, one connection in a loop and insert? Multiple connections?

Comment: Updated the question. It is single connection. My understanding is record insertion latency is increased. Do I need any configuration to optimize the performance?